# How configure security to query second same server database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, permissions, logins

I have a database which holds all my permissions and a central database which holds all the logins for all my application. I need to create view that queries both database which reside on the same server. When I am in Sql Server Management Studio I can run the query with no problems. However, when I integrate it into my application I get a run-time exception.

```
Cannot open database "abc" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'WORKGROUP\HOME$'
```

The error is obviously the permissions but I don't usually have to give access to this role. If the query is on the same server shouldn't the regular connection string and database permissions be sufficient?

Comment: It means the Computer 'WORKGROUP\HOME$' don't have access to SQL Server. You should create new login [WORKGROUP\HOME$] and grant sufficient permission to it.

Comment: Does the login that your application use have a mapped user in both databases?

Comment: Yes, I think I may  have not configured networkserver for the application or rather database

Comment: If you add a user in the "abc" database for the application's login (assuming it is authenticating as the computer WORKGROUP\HOME$) that should give it access.
Depending on which database your view is in you may need to explicitly grant SELECT to the tables or the db_datareader role if cross-database ownership chaining is not configured either.